Confirm a multisg transaction via the safe-apps-react-sdk
I am building a Safe App (Apps in the lateral navbar --> My custom app) which is a basic React app.
My custom Safe app allows a UserA to send a transaction and UserB to sign/confirm it. Basically a 2 out of 2 multi-sig where a party sends a transaction, and the other party signs it.
The UserA can send the transaction via React using the safe-apps-react-sdk (https://github.com/safe-global/safe-apps-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-apps-react-sdk)
Example:
const { safe } = useSafeAppsSDK();

const txs = [
        {
          to: address,
          value: 10,
          data: "0x", 
        },
      ];

const txResponse = await sdk.txs.send({ txs });

I am struggling to understand how UserB (the confirmation party) can confirm the transaction via the safe-apps-react-sdk.
UserA and UserB are using two different machines with different Browsers. Example: UserA (in the USA) uses a Mac with Chrome and UserB (in Germany) uses a Windows on Chrome.
I understand this is possible using the safe-apps-sdk, but this is for the backend, requiring NodeJs.
I need to use safe-apps-react-sdk because I want to do everything via the frontend.

I think this is not the right way but you can do the following
Or you can just ditch the idea of using safe-react-sdk and manually send the transaction and signature. For that, you need to create a safe instance on your own and hit the execTransaction function which has around 6-7 parameters, including signature.
Whenever user A signs you just keep the signature in the redux or any storage and when user B signs, concatenate the signature and hit the execTransaction function.
If safe-react-sdk provides you the functionality to send a signature along with the transaction then you can store the signature, concatenate it, and pass it with your transaction

Thanks! Two things: a) Could you show me how you would use execTransaction?
b) Perhaps I should have been more clear: UserA and UserB are on two different machines (PCs) and so they have two different browsers

You can use this file from safe. This file includes a function named as executeContractCallWithSigners where you just have to enter your safe address,target address,target function name, function parameters, signer of the owner. By doing this you can create a safe transaction https://github.com/safe-global/safe-smart-account/blob/main/src/utils/execution.ts. But still you need a database if user A and user B are on different PC's . You can use this function to get signature from one user and store it in database and then same for the other user and then execute.
